# To Keep One's Thoughts to Oneself

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

At the end of episode 16 of "The World at War" (ITV, 1973) there is newsreel footage, from October 1944, showing Goebbels addressing the newly-formed Volksturm: old men; veterans of the First War; boys; no uniforms (an armband); little equipment. When Goebbels had finished a strangely subdued speech (for him) the Volksturm departed. Narrator, the late Sir Laurence Olivier, cut in:

> "They marched-off through that same Brandenburg Gate, where, four-years earlier the army had returned from France. They marched-off keeping their thoughts to themselves.".

Is there a Latin idiom for keeping one's thought to oneself? I had thought that it was to do with keeping thoughts "in the heart"--"in pectore". It turns out that this is a Medieval construction; still used by the Vatican for referring to things to be kept secret (Wiki: "In pectore").

Similarly, "in animo"--"in the mind/ soul/ spirit". Of the many contexts for "animus" (Lewis & Short), this does not appear to be one of them.

I found this, on the net, but could not find an attestation: "sibi cogitationes suas reservare" -- "to keep one's thoughts to oneself".

Here's a guess: using neuter noun, "silentium"--"omission to speak or write of" (Oxford):

> "cum suis cogitationibus silentiis, recesserunt." --

> "They marched-off with their thoughts unspoken."

Any thoughts?